# LINQ to Objects and sort order

Tags: linq, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to use an ArrayList that contains custom objects. The array list is sorted. I am using LINQ to objects to search on multiple fields. Will LINQ to objects search use underlying sort, or it will scan through the entire arraylist.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayLists` anymore, instead use stringly typed `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ extension methods will not take advantage of the underlying sort. These methods are written to work on IEnumerable, and thus cannot assume anything about the underlying collection. From looking at the implementation, some LINQ methods will check if the input is an ICollection and if so call the corresponding method on that (I believe Count() works this way) to possibly avoid doing a linear scan, but in this case there is no way for LINQ to detect that your array is sorted, so it will cannot take advantage of that fact.

Furthermore, if you are doing something like myList.Where(o => o.Prop1 < 2 && o.Prop2 == 3), the Func<> passed to Where() is totally opaque to LINQ, so there's no way that it could figure out which properties are being examined even if it did know that the list was sorted.